# plot of polynomial expression failed

Tags: plotting, polynomials, arbitrary-precision

I want to plot a polynomial expression for {a,0,1}:

```
expr[a_]:= (7593091509776607082206602920903426144808982146770366365696+4383873427150986011348603179693543155639766802908526936064 Sqrt[3]-336996551647191914864349058266966093927040304746359916855296 a-194565049809481873884602635915637380185097204853538921381888 Sqrt[3] a+7395410980427470892549584624249463909201276643237369251954688 a^2+4269742520317714515826085475231601165969947470030527949570048 Sqrt[3] a^2-106983439567060931502019420333286893472518987569940106355081216 a^3-61766917632874688859803732532743294305497468613239257013420032 Sqrt[3] a^3+1147593693534152256081385176195628174486139309817420424500412416 a^4+662563527882259697217836028595565353419643624235901278009032704 Sqrt[3] a^4-9735361075681870048545253736749895047409687200111019655642808320 a^5-5620713337703132317699428951919566798444131859398589667596042240 Sqrt[3] a^5+68027113761537744167204787146767941220885613544609948340050198528 a^6+39275472442417111902971295402571835157093622723299903335181582336 Sqrt[3] a^6-402676471018165610925934847545202158517556484256607645750621634560 a^7-232485368938666453021303569312784434241802415894254108080026943488 Sqrt[3] a^7+2060971089751553873976862972790993101773972397311627163298835529728 a^8+1189902213460095990833925827653835870039699202769794415973445009408 Sqrt[3] a^8-9264231446096456118831827362545425127554121440480851648709268996096 a^9-5348706519238784910709988945821018213691351783640002449107031031808 Sqrt[3] a^9+37025705167148058936939655829234878567402517942853846121464044568576 a^10+21376800845188649438880755339888844309958719228882453244009882681344 Sqrt[3] a^10-132879081746821489303286450000894850613334616262954262749935929671680 a^11-76717773616197674207747756398439288973566583582529811604102661210112 Sqrt[3] a^11+431727703357803357308629912415844537623142986075362540487276639600640 a^12+249258105750246667400243056619684636957668377557561958717728768688128 Sqrt[3] a^12-1278570455642561713364965247844588348263557044649717266019065623298048 a^13-738182996743135473190395045108947684235226645630288620004573586128896 Sqrt[3] a^13+3471455594588852545739753118611389834739770063048292710716867725058048 a^14+2004245822015706382767654079444732350755681622997643880827083461476352 Sqrt[3] a^14-8684080776020477354412701708743799292292173845082368219273366371688448 a^15-5013756373699876806290666703426517897297889068055689464472827801108480 Sqrt[3] a^15+20101374095818755575962677616034818172571941338727523151724909560449024 a^16+11605533745302328737631332694498920862504188191644504049707852594778112 Sqrt[3] a^16-43216053089752515936536691566380247720079426745007562977584751581765632 a^17-24950799884681773325598527938362957072863770000541428577048984155729920 Sqrt[3] a^17+86579164951696593586446770448522352699827735371311343603574160801537536 a^18+49986504191075040658047883579697236781334929675920971951625558688443392 Sqrt[3] a^18-162105313672670611296961553338054980729771599972792974034064521461234176 a^19-93591546485985099416870725059244788373271196261248055678690783823816704 Sqrt[3] a^19+284395981757484269917959379866374694771575368276297637145515180689107456 a^20+164196096624131441464495340589579934106597737353828348458145306653223936 Sqrt[3] a^20-468596500320103738052618386702365013675500367757215445196364301394765312 a^21-270544315601128448892096014289906032089602321689622570605448550626484224 Sqrt[3] a^21+726653926835340923085831285291070827278171921834345048458390685683991040 a^22+419533840266082707060039588087203928599357488487218179168833987438859264 Sqrt[3] a^22-1062485035131833208027033118976481017773777724231015721970044111144307200 a^23-613426021043312890183944203244629710053180336839717664555876656435970048 Sqrt[3] a^23+1467301435577882830530970098741475456145231433599612766161573175648329472 a^24+847146878813214979144364549134515680115892470328412058628974481191826944 Sqrt[3] a^24-1916824100087593062722635470924708726544813054998312106514577714685148160 a^25-1106678910174734013734118415963561982510558399945975163715577305596615168 Sqrt[3] a^25+2372000661150327925015405188301663788827864119977244155534267699876833472 a^26+1369475220233112115732693310216068438515566195452405766455613936645046144 Sqrt[3] a^26-2783972545011976727625337946213109083454096512494200069012623474731542336 a^27-1607327298279192294136605296831999486013241178163672271026397457851251456 Sqrt[3] a^27+3102637307159077083721737207354894967692329497056980864308675034954963136 a^28+1791308484486068751443127160629205061017588447122281722930811929015435392 Sqrt[3] a^28-3286748400505054190717960675015946595021194304802428426013680664898659136 a^29-1897605073790164951065584725562080936956253915976621918420543838439066624 Sqrt[3] a^29+3312714658519645263875584435803047503386156710215011255438425685518405280 a^30+1912596699844736384605596127250727820097504729626128708659695346149625920 Sqrt[3] a^30-3179503182510359624710252167407846649894578366952900687369348309125998368 a^31-1835687018311627946356001685638430409903587664427962769640272259629231616 Sqrt[3] a^31+2908262453667200352005863400104080753715178210203948506664816199629496700 a^32+1679086110498839650877375673781812037717149948310771818338740343133770808 Sqrt[3] a^32-2536979799844055545478088373860336868089745306053262604755425658613127408 a^33-1464725970368608361322412341172458308966503268586162398640931303401037608 Sqrt[3] a^33+2111982664640845950993174830556388267404728845869401184864209135675874261 a^34+1219353759954215525606059902792308820715465749507657788821981042773286098 Sqrt[3] a^34-1678832393987758672137948634465618971816217779255167246541364812323318631 a^35-969274334593096328258580660134740907631220464275970288923174854589212524 Sqrt[3] a^35+1274959347296786593747645986974453251821173084021868767277814238015033115 a^36+736098122367629303685035618146556616698635382837702828619168674684731002 Sqrt[3] a^36-925468935314447729236158609979948890551446684273910599113822397708231605 a^37-534319738930432750449405448700857299174450732867905002219582884610210368 Sqrt[3] a^37+642370881544955565035683420977970549157693097746429765909060554803693558 a^38+370873001379557300577776868034996189969894867580878824045619193849420236 Sqrt[3] a^38-426509724922553275916595768983674475915572306113551843071256397657407538 a^39-246245504496029370676303700879916919500007945052191983438282286961535352 Sqrt[3] a^39+270976308102052253233682803848814366621482423015406722706107214888867398 a^40+156448244426730837444241191965228380499338478347892154954952703787881460 Sqrt[3] a^40-164783468181816570725482448016861241935767716984193818878200748999424974 a^41-95137779712771929149460776520648013631072459018697597393827086841473032 Sqrt[3] a^41+95935133684006530544690659520105784110777440130877230527578506853825207 a^42+55388175257203904475850998053750973970075651161264897474448183692646230 Sqrt[3] a^42-53481920429721396290556846044766374920259440069564945611729123504060861 a^43-30877801156877793792311979868176433882319830776689468381521706480536692 Sqrt[3] a^43+28554023789570759108325489500209726004293001955081974074179546742763001 a^44+16485673321355655756635698321362774425737947705681443565727440625911054 Sqrt[3] a^44-14601820293460621991206191703271493873443975060206841303188802338034991 a^45-8430364877088030383902884058871250778320863867979316337194569891925056 Sqrt[3] a^45+7152489826937811902135911555407303747353827291925387635896099950161092 a^46+4129491926958605499546562046443474344547016735599772581218653173218504 Sqrt[3] a^46-3356080099341714681216671988846019209762796908367200332322490990459500 a^47-1937633748776884948713307453387464326422719177485415156569089137467664 Sqrt[3] a^47+1508445368726256973842778312464514670624148346879386125595316390760400 a^48+870901339691948757476255327874817742890795657623356678023804998025488 Sqrt[3] a^48-649425827682552377997923614650130264021975202803655995578385807214532 a^49-374946176431217131109981592698624011298914443088321349694452010404664 Sqrt[3] a^49+267790863430200136810141850682836025945805220339471002851703593598323 a^50+154609127087948358917688952580473519912622804338810727640694470174942 Sqrt[3] a^50-105748579362043251714425833293864012813081518411083054254310010742513 a^51-61053970761096174974242310462152640059290202157092653833133959961108 Sqrt[3] a^51+39984789979835712154335977125534865384705712137670435528191445067197 a^52+23085229258348799356776544478415687760548094015519432736714285101878 Sqrt[3] a^52-14473302889344022259502846486869162601429825050643509211894777154755 a^53-8356165319225759610430288421195815747858456229910621569772485291136 Sqrt[3] a^53+5014016590041204217776710274230346940040261633731724492814753049734 a^54+2894843827981538705365436832273947928276964462992018750895379236908 Sqrt[3] a^54-1661969156493060559086669010167454392097647272015294389794940832610 a^55-959538339886123782312600485809528952874078414294296603197215696120 Sqrt[3] a^55+526906265313816920564880499041382626877061145376495210530152351310 a^56+304209474116632571889678303816010008509490885339085579634547249668 Sqrt[3] a^56-159716796670600400883604774052543521993027978764662512001398496286 a^57-92212535551875865515271923595695345769001281654611282106702772888 Sqrt[3] a^57+46268641033255490630079723876734931240284902735480093855022626209 a^58+26713212355588221889733952047167206226241567495672903943941833530 Sqrt[3] a^58-12803574740489115627939610289146503476905900222369949657085251787 a^59-7392147323010883747978312666011989534916929346506127275691027852 Sqrt[3] a^59+3382590962042940936282190583798967663882687233823588607633161999 a^60+1952939802493887136312764332576093169835239648591344541102641538 Sqrt[3] a^60-852670648200287978470309878237240941669155979453250733739428089 a^61-492289628268528953786790670352066574430814756551738439230659072 Sqrt[3] a^61+204945899793394112879710138464377773244070582813172673128691136 a^62+118325570415026158425454768841036016442525523915976867831559488 Sqrt[3] a^62-46936033085263607400148561316999344094610377228828968780405440 a^63-27098531336470124825205975217943283670973784141018270566888448 Sqrt[3] a^63+10233735320414591745485812434955870289034499667221774222856832 a^64+5908449842056745619699308959860055673204476608532324987052544 Sqrt[3] a^64-2122460697297344733884701016428170493444317723958291363751808 a^65-1225403254929022787459695552845918111110517531933517884035072 Sqrt[3] a^65+418313938754822375400617762897589916432934818086811952805888 a^66+241513665145869323925982081578727040540070879781818189298688 Sqrt[3] a^66-78263751261272543779142038447810104166250137420529079140352 a^67-45185597858485616099474595725580215693483942169605173751808 Sqrt[3] a^67+13883783608573963917571050560271194941859286194864943252480 a^68+8015806203780691855261366219021494126539588836969479776256 Sqrt[3] a^68-2332313909301890019269032650507248759461839179447719885824 a^69-1346562063370154612960083568356830340759764102420909785088 Sqrt[3] a^69+370497754381707284619425771523897743762958781362011947008 a^70+213906978226430549377839103107572876716409293106474926080 Sqrt[3] a^70-55568495367789075805550203754695432210816618470453657600 a^71-32082485759055495268335897971536213834047259557302894592 Sqrt[3] a^71+7855449641744575435153718375063741107411702746428571648 a^72+4535345965266779900655725374336184343931563841024425984 Sqrt[3] a^72-1044691763065290608243878931705951849763179141441028096 a^73-603153070625930271480443376020691859989631766907322368 Sqrt[3] a^73+130426150188690904574455920969233285611434887839088640 a^74+75301572920807252955431022976118306782591902733565952 Sqrt[3] a^74-15250394361599700847869741474026956988173325349814272 a^75-8804819289917538244721445494683695608511459022602240 Sqrt[3] a^75+1665701980459091977430012486537276161720052449148928 a^76+961693486807749508154023160996259872635603274956800 Sqrt[3] a^76-169446471588425615031346519520341024732000973881344 a^77-97829965984809802843134510753722745063270399344640 Sqrt[3] a^77+16000739803704634235090127338551400931877453824000 a^78+9238031432902030289710976843556477156748720865280 Sqrt[3] a^78-1397255213819805682574131930914896391153647616000 a^79-806705673825472917663238630962974145537638400000 Sqrt[3] a^79+112345991968779757136172962103107259020083200000 a^80+64862988705550526240671028975665921507983360000 Sqrt[3] a^80-8275866650354247790541188492878754951987200000 a^81-4778073838359469002528630507488687633203200000 Sqrt[3] a^81+555280067273893115205877158397794582528000000 a^82+320591096316223638919998150302944041369600000 Sqrt[3] a^82-33703078801098554606513504901761335296000000 a^83-19458481618321607787199428485342822400000000 Sqrt[3] a^83+1835358462569170416852812930088960000000000 a^84+1059644702433636781392991041198489600000000 Sqrt[3] a^84-88784370445642289124717543948288000000000 a^85-51259680174037240274210437201920000000000 Sqrt[3] a^85+3768362180894327593790425006080000000000 a^86+2175664914780566041309080453120000000000 Sqrt[3] a^86-138151843061654176478936432640000000000 a^87-79762011296172608584050278400000000000 Sqrt[3] a^87+4285648456984966979911680000000000000 a^88+2474314513478758999837900800000000000 Sqrt[3] a^88-109371377881238478520320000000000000 a^89-63148351081807872000000000000000000 Sqrt[3] a^89+2205301110197059584000000000000000 a^90+1272426140464526131200000000000000 Sqrt[3] a^90-32801985263960064000000000000000 a^91-19055657054896128000000000000000 Sqrt[3] a^91+322860356075520000000000000000 a^92+186820167204864000000000000000 Sqrt[3] a^92-3134566563840000000000000000 a^93)/(15186183019553214164413205841806852289617964293540732731392+8767746854301972022697206359387086311279533605817053872128 Sqrt[3]-679224711195743255794366468173094990519178152914301340614656 a-392150569849108185521811890904277427487826800197270751346688 Sqrt[3] a+15023011158108564579014976138075823551628812572549987037609984 a^2+8673539536172731266983977392203986307600222585376808340553728 Sqrt[3] a^2-219061850020406880166701500788670509677657794013118589973823488 a^3-126475418078459338538604020357902717367943317698693323804770304 Sqrt[3] a^3+2368879610833523927585514757990981458878789978644593317791137792 a^4+1367673280992550961043875282622087229195446665414104798038589440 Sqrt[3] a^4-20261003679563557656704301736381908986052741364250032286347296768 a^5-11697695928448018128155154383363323347910087989407529593970819072 Sqrt[3] a^5+142756114734178906406970100845846272771659562399306168329690939392 a^6+82420281270243292503014444964517384044364235251778970339408347136 Sqrt[3] a^6-852163213950530769773965371997162429865650164597719537182780686336 a^7-491996660967835593553718693314684487548099543717633520138784079872 Sqrt[3] a^7+4398886193959131486538797870860338240622227975776202383833758826496 a^8+2539698128216832896277784863810407694391598801824558807667523846144 Sqrt[3] a^8-19945060760119114163206932327775442682803980263442563429570168422400 a^9-11515286198858212428988243399359374820025419220423628683118972583936 Sqrt[3] a^9+80414750395197202072075207981423603707527090356355369566410086154240 a^10+46427477787483669445861622187969465781747240773789659358371190013952 Sqrt[3] a^10-291170343947011614873660280467001592733190548339702410717242425999360 a^11-168107276457843076666776042468486882714378477773097056619194807189504 Sqrt[3] a^11+954576626736791030622187413263423770855104104599697580494364388687872 a^12+551125072408611216354035491904840954689148618806443966252749222608896 Sqrt[3] a^12-2852913693971734677810678224311426185340341775529553602200758540140544 a^13-1647130489189350634928633314726831318222360319107137480072698174103552 Sqrt[3] a^13+7817933161699620504478684317682754947306270531969655837052500194492416 a^14+4513685815413777948127401307577230305531826079603903015915565054443520 Sqrt[3] a^14-19741239684798289776833916050550664326444893833030514622486445919600640 a^15-11397610046155215480983234396046260708671469348397326573977347981213696 Sqrt[3] a^15+46131864654415562252362709919379751040644336251445396356875426147618816 a^16+26634244476446207007513986054193745790056293518402565226779636177027072 Sqrt[3] a^16-100138289735779345572967635313862613463606264409035822150368979883268096 a^17-57814868535140943838982628016970222182269703382711474703882106961299968 Sqrt[3] a^17+202583492555700736625904851652463829911617172547502217125232219395330048 a^18+116961633960408367427272521392567482975792720695464216604374876674996224 Sqrt[3] a^18-383071638412279201439161890371836112332000507408604848819242313345277952 a^19-221166513556240382149705952637437819840547670451096878752574673133573120 Sqrt[3] a^19+678821408411379234253706317803150583197377868574964420503863249063628800 a^20+391917722877990692092576262691017450844468452002719570018130923117318144 Sqrt[3] a^20-1129895973569151882575771911284503536755224068007283244066077005074907136 a^21-652345744496424117310837715465026923731543090248604990008522466203275264 Sqrt[3] a^21+1770244392342044915885978769617246311171114682107705153244697999192121344 a^22+1022051076450105118462746006015381528553347519863904279139394175002606592 Sqrt[3] a^22-2615497434177625741094546270161461963771586287764035582074784415656654848 a^23-1510058147687227715929909965389323157617027077898924671250897531799083008 Sqrt[3] a^23+3650373298664488956828324871078193723895358040083370153920308441998148096 a^24+2107544006626564867475399762636451861897684875130212253953550196939436544 Sqrt[3] a^24-4820012659634264284058438425573643694856301130237470555900903610475051776 a^25-2782835606537246511545154729824156270876971241221160474200365865850630208 Sqrt[3] a^25+6029637493023426746262161403526798504840402978236303838041011506337908224 a^26+3481212829712935674583848173947368899667658306214981320648163763882289152 Sqrt[3] a^26-7155093982775898669883225193002797877130328531983215734978031862694683136 a^27-4130995437032736630392512265538175231809349302490428328723680337876742016 Sqrt[3] a^27+8063433082846489152858273822223214726999899275917845515502098611345879808 a^28+4655425260973954461011434431255123391449775547113076856068762342503498624 Sqrt[3] a^28-8638925189203674209529372347745122328439617970522567378008327123614147712 a^29-4987685783495779994200234986891604034446159453846836694932275020472682400 Sqrt[3] a^29+8807414089952747753945721520361293605174956613470103500919614006781378048 a^30+5084962895698721743185646791196122241962216268713757368643541972889600192 Sqrt[3] a^30-8551904665536322415794989815397018499262763945236423251970882328889740672 a^31-4937444460731412236241648658043998494006350504320798398894651417991057536 Sqrt[3] a^31+7914905147061922426535492981684025328323535075450338803025369563068157496 a^32+4569672617266555412146413309878654863315373225649296017802353019414432592 Sqrt[3] a^32-6987282582862972185856288742601245039766457433899222278079482617469440676 a^33-4034109480119920583260497115023499113251803572708374401668811492000345479 Sqrt[3] a^33+5887526183838721908395936625674330344314582274682677523957092511026283640 a^34+3399164827100256200106636240677973067541345740452964196361313389844849356 Sqrt[3] a^34-4737775805977294188618568914152382355986633279162499360957303685315757120 a^35-2735356136941086966972460452055490027985894936570915999180876720068144982 Sqrt[3] a^35+3643033130599053065094930828467542874426838699637483077230354211046771200 a^36+2103306158618088360799835915270032905518441863595935546514529815257035084 Sqrt[3] a^36-2677964186620207157429547176635901847904246117852173648693767881640805492 a^37-1546123344025353809393651970890369493472539834468673426852117405958794621 Sqrt[3] a^37+1882708347616322530267060544820198973624237346542442467079113518743971344 a^38+1086982171301839331404949445293238930169240557332208313404927291905347912 Sqrt[3] a^38-1266369001291424409194134785327726898427044150306912394295445403137898976 a^39-731138483789001420061973364445917335154788222411819507830891185995397180 Sqrt[3] a^39+815226728301279732070160401171205207231573178755256464933487878041447560 a^40+470671371035321757957377320408059891460263949413371752334329541456932056 Sqrt[3] a^40-502411951935745983329854086095902224780977808161404996105211261851088436 a^41-290067675694188264675510315974766285242361023033511692129951680041407487 Sqrt[3] a^41+296489049989483945394471447288494363078167527333053197645969484749674216 a^42+171178032823204965817526524550322123483707884072139092563187678403837988 Sqrt[3] a^42-167575319752654464104932443973274418046619971935981625557992191222590048 a^43-96749655968732666435995754232995408219809733111139422643308430536651274 Sqrt[3] a^43+90726054458726787463073559919565831460532387873250541083354662772498352 a^44+52380711964258557576946080913714820392085936972726749985031527039194020 Sqrt[3] a^44-47057095362753435887503266570513417971212398907535816894949145133633220 a^45-27168426674967586474066304834567683491102958778036579313005642599984509 Sqrt[3] a^45+23384218157659888843120813611424489246487118419130247744047483606717216 a^46+13500884648113871479680875570050913473152893859117841923677062722818544 Sqrt[3] a^46-11133761362900184271749504402654937552333624391743502221309516043604544 a^47-6428080119963476019746515186081236508238225687184259685767657360812552 Sqrt[3] a^47+5079046550886136492527499236835341192313396987782241027573381949481288 a^48+2932388893380751177520807041184335877765626861586700037453053892662048 Sqrt[3] a^48-2219866529519520588046375804423581465572256567594713841335260558388076 a^49-1281640538383135540028023235963045877060077986805631227598598031517789 Sqrt[3] a^49+929484652896398883886952284369002133765554687080866684874876725445832 a^50+536638214557361762648432095693905203301908333973112216621980262117716 Sqrt[3] a^50-372801409889388963657775953781818724461792651017114087846897618438400 a^51-215236994353910730773812091799031380615696258226961650218316714343946 Sqrt[3] a^51+143207179489310770188348872693295017417047153548385037340370394410272 a^52+82680703628040626686699847741822224814278717527678272612353057053012 Sqrt[3] a^52-52676659765311386594798545546362463528784571059472073704568068863196 a^53-30412883695512857799055423733363973827824372735231088780948167099551 Sqrt[3] a^53+18549574645911926472851469557751595778197268298762153554635525442832 a^54+10709601915170307772959588990135566674842088298019791125875644861448 Sqrt[3] a^54-6251572960957188726676583950874145724442689829970164277609961814112 a^55-3609347331867218710936723052916869161441385787322949904023371551164 Sqrt[3] a^55+2015775340649078088318317724246585045157494954339459772607985777144 a^56+1163808435549554808941857740571650149749449519867179547826101762104 Sqrt[3] a^56-621627127327209731695770554663976949695098376366036835516412822460 a^57-358896589297938308873019073064155670404847782470853803186697959261 Sqrt[3] a^57+183260563148602355921718884739607092976697559704583150241769200344 a^58+105805535465687981556869000561860872017668315546948111108253096508 Sqrt[3] a^58-51624168343066666843758645742598024010880533603938744190668353632 a^59-29805227489560096776380448250046026825671210707498952637407003606 Sqrt[3] a^59+13888396196960560535143048547721212386722040043310030582973161264 a^60+8018469282927354354010223788662143861267209358390821451501277372 Sqrt[3] a^60-3566241755752382077817398423799992010761699251363991626464125548 a^61-2058970637678921409377648400103617973172878658586551327264768199 Sqrt[3] a^61+873467468340845622769947628891106232711720818308546112690376384 a^62+504296677974968140451705348593873151533132800427700794581704064 Sqrt[3] a^62-203914682794332272455326869180928772723045892509090336836922368 a^63-117730197003024886796980082509912312819609740430260750127743168 Sqrt[3] a^63+45339133581860038838948329462521871612804863246913668958154496 a^64+26176560978311294811659896670412262964432645063190664576538624 Sqrt[3] a^64-9592768778346860992009208976847213391326842257148399222953472 a^65-5538387636452397682395640351004054069236973088676938127485056 Sqrt[3] a^65+1929508655851740245249046613730337048186606791769557971860480 a^66+1114002341859715208705569328260531687618156415366429729335296 Sqrt[3] a^66-368575742225851529315168651126529346293642567251224796209152 a^67-212797303990861496103278052982122263150011024394613251546112 Sqrt[3] a^67+66785855247657225851042268023460020420113607781497095581696 a^68+38558831505294279824627354789964067756565088302210992828416 Sqrt[3] a^68-11464914522124457968141100899438427287518755527465699479552 a^69-6619271485584605440675350527040411788790513109482253698048 Sqrt[3] a^69+1862007334142461801955508931518185141840687021919451987968 a^70+1075030435600207769939644175145371435177374797515782324224 Sqrt[3] a^70-285660399400325887416758069663528344375562298824221261824 a^71-164926108490594161414004568870024626279034231963746746368 Sqrt[3] a^71+41327680632029601530864554685841238408528917037701070848 a^72+23860547537885173495046016703576174059109574458114572288 Sqrt[3] a^72-5627814365725293147131197353184569063688986745581993984 a^73-3249220139000740980216282330638629169617833417519759360 Sqrt[3] a^73+719849426772676483256334758908513270916884688816308224 a^74+415605260323202567341260154179596473159166206377197568 Sqrt[3] a^74-86285692519978946274340385977070171721235139326377984 a^75-49817067803623122916129245986646788515461582420443136 Sqrt[3] a^75+9667262037091723252540480448237437839281377395081216 a^76+5581396339441556352021767494496449256619459129901056 Sqrt[3] a^76-1009411641472688633696423448009980476173071323496448 a^77-582784082927398793036595982249843009039836618817536 Sqrt[3] a^77+97904121805235089331588309888082583119905591132160 a^78+56524971079026388378803037856238725332570849935360 Sqrt[3] a^78-8787653510841256306415175053165691798628073472000 a^79-5073554120029359261919665457092033740586614784000 Sqrt[3] a^79+726806955505586964098092321214052007327825920000 a^80+419622191410042988946221471668783450234552320000 Sqrt[3] a^80-55117010656942639432370043230271460972953600000 a^81-31821820939713299268144806564385065612083200000 Sqrt[3] a^81+3810318360945526855107098947494873346867200000 a^82+2199888331390086934786036627707236922163200000 Sqrt[3] a^82-238497515872805424670774403677292593152000000 a^83-137696604990205579099331477972009877504000000 Sqrt[3] a^83+13406400366908386484872337480692531200000000 a^84+7740188860706671730648760871236403200000000 Sqrt[3] a^84-670104916104839016260933956141056000000000 a^85-386885253702206074154413454917632000000000 Sqrt[3] a^85+29419860861155829143331038822400000000000 a^86+16985564577306983712601040486400000000000 Sqrt[3] a^86-1116926835535993582792873082880000000000 a^87-644858017138981323076439900160000000000 Sqrt[3] a^87+35925060998153687230159257600000000000 a^88+20741341902450836981258649600000000000 Sqrt[3] a^88-951877700308065520189440000000000000 a^89-549564829273498968391680000000000000 Sqrt[3] a^89+19946130241188947558400000000000000 a^90+11518053108224517734400000000000000 Sqrt[3] a^90-310868758228893696000000000000000 a^91-178490996931428352000000000000000 Sqrt[3] a^91+2969061449269248000000000000000 a^92+1953461882585088000000000000000 Sqrt[3] a^92-37614798766080000000000000000 a^93+3134566563840000000000000000 Sqrt[3] a^93
)
```

```
Plot[expr[a], {a, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

but it doesn't work without WorkingPrecision->60. How to fix it?

Comment: Use `WorkingPrecision->60` would be a  good way to go. Voting to close (it's simply not broken).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)

$HistoryLength = 0; (* for comparing timings *)

expr[a_] = `<your expression>`
```

The need to use high precision for **plotting or any other numeric evaluation** is to be expected since:

The polynomials in the [`Numerator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Numerator.html) and [`Denominator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Denominator.html) of the rational polynomial are of very high degree

```
(Cases[#[expr[a]], a^n_ :> n, Infinity] // Max) & /@ {Numerator, Denominator}

(* {93, 93} *)
```

The integer factors have length up to

```
Cases[expr[a], x_Integer :> Length[IntegerDigits[x]], Infinity] // Max

(* 73 *)
```

There are many irrational factors

```
Count[expr[a], Sqrt[3], Infinity]

(* 187 *)
```

And the resulting [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html) is very high

```
LeafCount[expr[a]]

(* 2793 *)

Plot[expr[a], {a, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 60] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

A smooth curve can still be obtained with a lower [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) of 45

```
Plot[expr[a], {a, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 45] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

The `LeafCount` can be reduced using [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html)

```
expr2[a_] = expr[a] // Simplify;

LeafCount[expr2[a]]

(* 2594 *)

Plot[expr2[a], {a, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 45] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

The `LeafCount` can be further reduced by using [`HornerForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HornerForm.html)

```
expr3[a_] = HornerForm[expr[a]];

LeafCount[expr3[a]]

(* 2059 *)
```

`HornerForm` enables a minor reduction in the `WorkingPrecision` and a significant timing improvement

```
Plot[expr3[a], {a, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 43] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Depending on what you intend to do with an approximate function, use [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) on sampled data

```
if = Interpolation[
  Table[{a, expr[a]}, {a, 0, 1, 1/100}] // N[#, 45] & // 
   N] (* after high precision calculation reduce points to machine precision *)
```

[image]

```
plt1 = Plot[Evaluate[expr[a] // HornerForm], {a, 0, 1}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 45, PlotStyle -> Thick];

plt2 = Plot[if[a], {a, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dotted}}];

Show[plt1, plt2]
```

[image]

Looking at the derivative of the [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) (note that the additional complexity of the derivative requires even higher `WorkingPrecision`)

```
plt3 = Plot[Evaluate[expr'[a] // Simplify], {a, 0, 1}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 100, PlotStyle -> Thick];

plt4 = Plot[if'[a], {a, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dotted}}];

Show[plt3, plt4]
```

[image]

Comment: Moreover...Is there any way to simplify my expression?

Comment: @GaeP - you can use an approximation. See edit.